# Display button with fixed distance to table bottom in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table

I have a big table in my ASP.NET web app, this table acts as my container (it has only borders), I draw everything else in this table, I have some buttons (which are aligned horizontally), I want to display these buttons so that their distance to bottom border of table is always constant, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you add a piece of relevant code? And perhaps an image that gives an impression of what you are seeing now, and how it is different from what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: in this link, you can see that my buttons (3 buttons) are near the gray line: http://www.homezlab.info/main/businessPageFrm.aspx?city=%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86&bcode=6329&tit=%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%AA%D8%B2%D8%A7%20%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%88%D8%AF%20%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86,    but in this link: http://www.homezlab.info/main/businessPageFrm.aspx?bcode=40&tit=%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%86%20%D8%B3%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%A7%20%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86&city=%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86, the same buttons are located further from the red line beneath them, I want to have this disatance always the same, thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided any HTML code so I came up with something that most likely simulates your situation. The idea is that you position a div (here: `.wrapper`) absolutely in your table cell (here `td#yourTD`) in such way that it will also be at the bottom right of the td. Feel free to change the width and height of the `td` so you can see that the buttons always remain at the same distance from the bottom.

**Live demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/SR2GM/1/

**CSS**

```
#yourTD {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px; /* change for another 'same distance' */
    right: 0;
    background: blue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="yourTD">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <button>button X</button>
                <button>button Y</button>
                <button>button Z</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Bazzz for providing me this nice fiddle, I thanks it is what I'm looking for, I'll test it in my code

Comment: thanks, I think my buttons are now located at bottom of my page, but I want them to be in my white table (container): http://www.homezlab.info/main/businessPageFrm.aspx?bcode=40&tit=%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%86%20%D8%B3%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%A7%20%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86&city=%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86, how can I bring them inside my white bi table?

Comment: look at this fiddle please: http://jsfiddle.net/SR2GM/4/, I want my buttons to be inside the rectangular border (i.e. top of hello 123), but now they are attached to screen bottom

Comment: I don't see them being at the screen bottom, but I do recognise the problem though. If the buttons are at screen bottom instead of in your `td` it means you didn't specify `position: relative` for your `td`. The `position:absolute` for the wrapper will look at the first parent with a `position` other than `static`(default). You'd want this to be your `td` hence specifying `position:relative` on the `td`.

Comment: thanks but you've set td position: relative and then the DIV inside this TD has position: absolute, but as you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SR2GM/4/, buttons are still positioned at the bottom of page (and not inside TD), also this is a part of my code: <td style="position:relative;"><div style="position: absolute; bottom: 20px;">, cell has position:relative and the DIV inside it has position: absolute, what is going wrong?

Comment: For me it is working as expected using Opera 12, Chrome 23 and IE 9. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using firefox, I put position: relative for the table and it works, but my site still has some problem

Comment: remarkable. I must admit I never use tables for layout so didn't find this issue myself but indeed Firefox doesn't support `position:relative` on `td`. You could add a `div` in the `td` and add `position:relative` to that `div`. Not very beautiful though. like this: http://jsfiddle.net/SR2GM/5/

Comment: thanks dear Bazzz, I changed my html a bit based on your tips and finally it worked!

Comment: Perfect! Just for the sake of future reference could you please add the HTML in which you managed to get it working to your question? Imagine someone uses the search engine and ends up on this page, they might find your HTML useful.

Comment: In fact I just added position: relative to my table, nothing more! my page is really messy with several tables defined in other tables and divs,